# Reformatting a HDD

Tags: 14.04, boot, hard-drive

OK, I have a computer that was given to me by a friend to fix. Initially, he wanted Windows 8.1. I stripped the HDD, loaded 8.1 per the instructions and after initially working, the OS won't boot.

I have an .iso img of Ubuntu 14.04 that I've put on a DVD. The end goal is to get rid of Windows and load Ubuntu onto the HDD and just turn it into a Linux machine.

*Can I boot this OS from the DVD and then reformat the HDD with the Windows OS still on it?*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can erase the Windows system with the Ubuntu Live CD. Be sure to complete the installation of Ubuntu, otherwise you will be left without any OS in your computer!

See links for more info:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux